# How do I let a button serve two different functions when it is clicked? - jQuery/CSS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css

You can see the implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/Chandu/AdQfB/11/

If you click 'Register' the first time, you will see more fields.

What I want to happen is, when they click 'Submit' after they have clicked Register, it sends the info to the server.

The same would apply if they pressed 'Login' and filled out the username and password fields.

How do I achieve this?

I am using Rails on the back-end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this simply be checking what text the button contains:

```
$("input#register").click(function(e) {
    if (this.value == 'Register')
        // do one thing
    else if (this.value == 'Submit')
        // do another thing
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a `type="submit"` button, you can use the default behavior and just remove your `click` handler, like this:

```
$("input#register").click(function(e) {
  $("input#f_name").slideDown().prepend("<br /><br />").css({"display": "block"});
  $("input#l_name").slideDown().css({"display": "block"});
  $("input#confirm_pw").slideDown().css({"display": "block"})
  $("input#register").val('Submit');
  $("input#login").css({ 'color' : '#567603' });
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).unbind("click"); 
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/NfB5E/).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this could be shortened a tiny bit by using `.once('click', ...` and removing the `unbind` line

Comment: @Michael - you can, it's basically the same behavior, so either way - if you post that you'll get a +1 from me :)

Comment: I like the elegance of these solutions...but it restricts the UI to literally just one click. What happens if the user clicks it more than once - but has not entered the correct info (e.g. when I add JS validation, in theory they should be able to click that button a billion times - if the proper data is not entered it shouldn't submit).

Comment: @marcamillion - That should be a *different* handler, ideally a `.submit()` handler on the `<form>` that prevents submission *there* if it's invalid

Answer (score 0):

add a class to the register button at the same time you are expanding the form. tie the submit action to that class. remove that class when removing the extra form elements, for the login, extend your "if($("#confirm_pw").is(":visible"))" with a else{ and implement your login submit there.